Holder type inequality
Suppose $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded open connected subset of $\mathbb C$. $f,g:b\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb C$ are two function such that $\sup_{b\Omega}|f|<\infty$. Does the following hold?
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{b\Omega}f(\zeta).g(\zeta)d\zeta\right|\leq \sup_{b\Omega}|f|\left|\int_{b\Omega}g(\zeta)d\zeta\right| 
\end{align*}

Doesn’t this follow from Holder inequality with $p=\infty$ and $q=1$?

What have you tried?

@Pranay Not directly I am not taking |g| on the rhs

@BrunoB I tried breaking it into real and imaginary parts. But not getting a appropriate answer.

@Zackmath you are right, thanks for pointing that out!

@BrunoB Both side we will get $0$

@Zackmath It's my fault for taking the wrong counterexample. Anyway, I'm pretty sure that it can't be true without having $|g|$ in the RHS.

This is not true. Take any $g\ne0$ such that $\int g = 0$, then set
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{ \overline{ g(x)}}{|g(x)|} & \text{ if } g(x) \ne0,\\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Then the lhs is $\ne0$ (might even be $+\infty$), while the rhs is zero.
